# I can't call from my database in firebase, or the Textviews didn't change

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've been trying to call from my database and the textviews dont work, it's from a QR Scanner, it also cannot find the button123

`public class QR extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private CodeScanner codeScanner;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 101;

private DatabaseReference mbase;
public String decodedResult;
private Spinner spinnerLanguages;
private String itemID;








@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);
    setUpPermissions();
    codeScanner();
    mbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();




}


private void codeScanner() {
    CodeScannerView scannerView = findViewById(R.id.scannerView);
    TextView tv_textView = findViewById(R.id.tv_textView);

    codeScanner = new CodeScanner(this, scannerView);

    codeScanner.setCamera(CodeScanner.CAMERA_BACK);
    codeScanner.setFormats(CodeScanner.ALL_FORMATS);
    codeScanner.setAutoFocusMode(AutoFocusMode.SAFE);
    codeScanner.setScanMode(ScanMode.CONTINUOUS);
    codeScanner.setAutoFocusEnabled(true);
    codeScanner.setFlashEnabled(false);


    codeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv_textView.setText(result.getText());
                    decodedResult =result.getText();




                }
            });
        }
    });}
public void buttonPopupwindow(View view) {
    // Inflate popup window layout
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewPopupwindow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindowlayout, null);
    // Find views inside popup window layout
    Button btn123 = viewPopupwindow.findViewById(R.id.button123);
    TextView nameTextView = viewPopupwindow.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView emailTextView = viewPopupwindow.findViewById(R.id.email);
    TextView companyIDTextView = viewPopupwindow.findViewById(R.id.CompanyID);
    TextView statusTextView = viewPopupwindow.findViewById(R.id.status);
    EditText companyIDInput = viewPopupwindow.findViewById(R.id.companyIDinput);
    Spinner spinnerLanguages = viewPopupwindow.findViewById(R.id.spinner_languages);

    // Set up adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.languages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLanguages.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set up and show popup window
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(viewPopupwindow, 700, 500, true);
    popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

    // Set up database listener to get item data
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // Loop through all items in the "Item" node of the database
                Item item = snapshot.getValue(Item.class);
                if (item.getEmail().equals(decodedResult)) {

                    String name = item.getName();
                    String email = item.getEmail();
                    String CompanyID = item.getCompanyID();
                    String Status = item.getStatus();
                    itemID = snapshot.getKey();

                    // Set text for views in popup window
                    nameTextView.setText(name);
                    emailTextView.setText(email);
                    companyIDTextView.setText(CompanyID);
                    statusTextView.setText(Status);

                    // Update values for button and input fields based on item status
                    if (Status.equals("In Storage")) {
                        btn123.setText("Lend");
                        companyIDInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        spinnerLanguages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (Status.equals("Borrowed")) {
                        btn123.setText("Return");
                        companyIDInput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        spinnerLanguages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    // Set up button click listener to update item status and close popup window
                    btn123.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            switch(v.getId()) {
                                case R.id.button123:
                                    DatabaseReference itemRef = mbase.child(itemID);
                                    if (Status.equals("In Storage")) {
                                        String companyID1 = companyIDInput.getText().toString();
                                        String selectedLanguage = spinnerLanguages.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                        itemRef.child("Status").setValue("Borrowed");
                                        itemRef.child("CompanyID").setValue(companyID1);
                                        itemRef.child("cat").setValue(selectedLanguage);
                                    } else if (Status.equals("Borrowed")) {
                                        itemRef.child("Status").setValue("In Storage");
                                        itemRef.child("CompanyID").setValue("");
                                        itemRef.child("cat").setValue("");
                                    }
                                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    // Exit loop after finding matching item
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Handle errors
            Log.w("onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    };
    mbase.child("Item").addValueEventListener(postListener);
}









@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    codeScanner.startPreview();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    codeScanner.releaseResources();
    super.onPause();
}

private void setUpPermissions() {
    final int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        makeRequest();
    }
}

private void makeRequest() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

}`

I tried setting a value to my decoded to see if it can call from the database, it still doesnt.tried chatgpt too, he said it's right

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).